# submit button doesn't post the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

On click of delete link (which is a button) nothing happens. I mean form is not posted.Not sure why its happening.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegistrationNo)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MiddleName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateofBirth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
       <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="Delete" style="border: none; background: none; 
            text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;"> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you also include the form, e.g. @Html.BeginForm(Action, Controller) ?

Comment: i am not seeing the `form` tags, also if it does get posted the DisplayFor will not give you any thing on the server side you need to have `HiddenFor` for every display for in order to get the values posted back to server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you can try

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<table>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegistrationNo)
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.RegistrationNo)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MiddleName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.MiddleName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateofBirth)
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.DateofBirth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
       <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="Delete" style="border: none; background: none; 
            text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;"> 
    </td>
</tr>


</table>


}
```